# date-fns format MM dd, yyyy is not working in firefox. But it is working in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

import { format, parse } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), 'MMM dd, yyyy') returns the below exception in Fire fox.

```
370 | var originalDate = toDate(dirtyDate);
  371 | 
  372 | if (!isValid(originalDate)) {
> 373 |   throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
      | ^  374 | } // Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
  375 | // This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
  376 | // See an issue about UTC functions: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376
```

But it is working fine in chrome.

other format like
format(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd') is working fine. What is missing here?